# Create folder with same name as file and move file into folder then compress those folders into individual zip files

Tags: macos, terminal

So I followed solution here: [Script to create folder with same name as file and move file into folder](https://superuser.com/questions/1048996/script-to-create-folder-with-same-name-as-file-and-move-file-into-folder).
I want to create folder with same name as file in a folder, and move them into that folder.

```
for file in *; do if [[ -f "$file" ]]; then mkdir "${file%.*}"; mv "$file" "${file%.*}"; fi; done
```

And it works perfectly fine.
But after doing that, I want to zip those folders into individual zip files, and I followed solution here: [command to zip multiple directories into individual zip files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68489/command-to-zip-multiple-directories-into-individual-zip-files?newreg=51714d1dfe1c49ed85dd79fb2431cfb8).

```
for file in *; do zip -r "${file%.*}.zip" "$file"; rm -R "$file"; done
```

The question is, how can I combine those 2 into 1-time command? I'm new to coding and I still don't know how to combine those 2 into 1 command.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine them in a script file. However second command delete files after compressing. So you need to add a location parameter.

Create a file text file called zipfoldered.sh (with gedit or nano)
make it executable

```
sudo chmod +x zipfoldered.sh
```

paste this into the file

```
#!/bin/bash
(cd $1
for file in *; do if [[ -f "$file" ]]; then mkdir "${file%.*}"; mv "$file" "${file%.*}"; fi; done
for file in *; do zip -r "${file%.*}.zip" "$file"; rm -R "$file"; done )
```

You can now call the script with a location to run :

```
./wherever_it_is/zipfoldered.sh myFolder
```

myFolder being the folder where the files to be zipped are located ...

you can remove location parameter removing `(cd $1` and the `)` at the end. So that the script will run locally but  surely it will compress and delete itself too ...